# White space on image

Tags: html, css

I've look around for answers and can't seem to find any. I've posted an image, it's the call for your free consultation/we'll call you. It seems to have an unusual amount of whitspace on either side. It's making my site scroll way farther right than it should. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

http://gdrummer95.comule.com/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `#contactform` has a width of `85%`. That's causing the page to scroll to the right. Set the width directly on the image instead of the form.